# Mocking C++ classes that copy constructors

Tags: c++

I'm coming from C# to C++ and when I try to construct tests, copy constructors are making it hard for me to mock the usual way I am accustomed to.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class DB {
public:
    virtual int getValue() { return 42; }
    DB(const DB& source) { }
    DB() { }
};

class DB_Mock: public DB {
public:
    virtual int getValue() { return 999; }
};

class A {
public:
    A(DB db) {
        m_db = db;
    }
    void doIt() {
        cout << "Result:" << m_db.getValue() << endl;
    }
private:
    DB m_db;
};

int main() {
    /* prints 42 as expected */
    DB db;
    A a(db);
    a.doIt();

    /* prints 42, expected 999 */
    DB_Mock db_mock;
    A a2(db_mock);
    a2.doIt();
    return 0;
}
```

How do you approach problems like this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with copy constructors but object slicing. C++ classes and objects work fundamentally different ways than in C# or Java. There is no prescribed, standardized, accepted approach of "mocking" C++ classes. Different approaches are used in different situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

m_db is not a reference or pointer, c++ polymorphism is work with only base class pointer or reference.

```cpp
    A(DB db) {
        m_db = db; // m_db just sliced copy of base part of db.
    }
```

Change this to reference like

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(DB &db) : m_db(db) // it is initializing not copy
    {
    }
    void doIt()
    {
        std::cout << "Result:" << m_db.getValue() << std::endl;
    }

private:
    DB &m_db;  // Now m_db is reference
};
```

[Compile and Run Here](https://onlinegdb.com/Hkizb388w)

Above will work But, You can not change reference value if you want to change use smart pointer[Recommended].

Reference :

1. [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)
2. [Smart pointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp?view=vs-2019)
3. [override](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override)
4. See [virtual table](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/) to understand v_ptr

**Edit:**

As [Pete Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593860/pete-becker) said be aware of lifetimes, if you pass local variable reference like

```cpp
A make()
{
    DB db;
    A a(db);
    return a;
}

int main()
{
   const A &a = make();
   // Wrong db is destroyed (dangling reference).
   a.doIt(); // assume doIt(), getValue() are declared as const
   return 0;
}
```

Above code is Wrong (undefined behaviour), So i Recommend to use smart pointer(Heap storage) to avoid this problems.

Thanks.

Comment: Also, be aware of lifetimes; if the object that the reference refers to goes away, you've got a dangling reference. +1.